# Android ICS 4.0 update breaking spinning wheel animation

Tags: java, android, android-animation, android-spinner, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

My application has a spinning wheel for the initial app load. Works fine upto android 3.0 honeycomb. But in ICS 4.0 its broken. Its a simple spinning wheel animation. In ICS this wheel is spinning around a point near its circumference  instead of the center point. This gives a visual impression like a wobbling wheel instead of a consistent spinning wheel. Here is the code

Layout:

```
<ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/spinner_white_48"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        />
```

spinner_animation.xml

```
    <rotate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360"
    android:pivotX="50%" 
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:duration="1200">

    </rotate>
```

Java File  (Activity)

```
Animation rotateSpinner = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.spinner_animation);
rotateSpinner.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) { 
            } 
            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) { 
            }
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            }
        }); 
 findViewById(R.id.spinner).startAnimation(rotateSpinner);
```

---

### NOTE: The app wont even start on 4.0.2(Samsung Galaxy). But shows this distorted animation in 4.0.3 app app works fine(Nexus S).

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: `spinner_animation.xml` does not contain any layouts? How do I create it?

Answer (score 1):

If by "wobbling" you mean that it appears to be revolving around something other than its center point, then this is [a known bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22969).

Answer (score 1):

Until there is a better fix, you can use:

```
RotateAnimation rotation;
if(Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK) >=15){
    rotation = new RotateAnimation(0f,360f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.25f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.25f);
}else{
    rotation = new RotateAnimation(0f,360f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.5f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.5f);
}
```

Comment: The bug only appears at Android 4.0 ~ 4.0.3 (Build.VERSION.SDK 14 and 15) by testing, and the value should set to about 0.32f instead of 0.25f on Build.VERSION.SDK 14 by my experiment.

Answer (score 0):

Check the layout settings.  I have a feeling if you just drop the same view in a simple LinearLayout, it will work OK again.  It appears you're in a RelativeLayout and I have a feeling the layout_centerHorizontal or layout_alignParentTop are giving you grief.

Answer (score 0):

You should to add in your manifest this:

```
<supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
                  android:smallScreens="true"
                  android:normalScreens="true"
                  android:largeScreens="true"
                  android:anyDensity="true"/>
```